# Parenthesis-style query equivalence

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A cypher query in neo4j can be written with WHERE clause:

```
match (n:PERSON) where n.name = 'Jonash' return n
```

But it can be also written with parentheses:

```
match (n:PERSON {name: 'Jonash'}) return n
```

Is this always possible for different operators, like `contains`, `>` or `<`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 4.4 you can do node pattern predicates like this:

```
match (m:Movie where m.title contains "Matrix" and m.released = 1999) 
return m
```

From cypher manual: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#node-pattern-predicates

But the short hand (n:Label{propertyKeyName: propertyKeyValue}) syntax is only there for equality.

Comment: Indeed, many thanks